# How to make Company mode be case-sensitive on plain Text?

Tags: company-mode, dabbrev

By default, Company mode seems to convert every prediction into lower case.

E.g:

```
  HelloWorldOfGoo
  HelloWorldOfEmacs
  ->
  Hell
  [Helloworldofgoo]  //Company prediction
  [Helloworldofemacs]
```

This is not very practical for case sensitive programming languages without a special backend. How can I make company mode case sensitive?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

After some research, I came across the [company mode git hub ticket](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/14),

which says that company mode uses dabbrev for plain text as backend.

dabbrev has an option to downcase things, it is turned on by default but can be turned off:

```
(setq company-dabbrev-downcase nil)
```

Now all is well.

Comment: that only works for the `company-dabbrev` backend... unfortunately I'm seeing the lowercasing problem with the `company-ispell` backend.

Comment: This drove me crazy for so long, and since it only happened in some modes, and was only a minor annoyance, I just let it go forever. Finally decided to look into it today. Seems like a weird thing to enable by default, but I am sure there is a reason.

Comment: Thanks for this. One google, one solution. What a dumbarse default;)

Comment: Odd thing is that I had its value as `case-replace` and that was `t`, but didn't seem to act like the documentation would lead me to expect.